# how to return query result as time HH:MM?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT SUM(HOURS_WORKED) * 24 as TOTAL_HOURS
FROM(
SELECT  AL.END_TIME - AL.START_TIME as HOURS_WORKED
from FCXP.APPLIED_LABOR AL
where AL.TASK_CARD_EXECUTION_ID = '8ab4f8884428a1540144c998588a7b2c');
```

Hey guys, simple question that I can't think through just now -
this is returning `TOTAL_HOURS` as a decimal, so `10:30` hours is coming out as `10.50`. How would I change this? Thanks!

Comment: must have been asked before....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this one:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(HOURS_WORKED), 'HOUR'))||':'
   ||EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(HOURS_WORKED), 'HOUR')) AS TOTAL_HOURS
FROM (...
```

Comment: That worked thanks for the numtodsinterval( function!

Answer (score 0):

Check out below Query :

```
SELECT TRUNC(2.75) || 'hrs:' ||
   SUBSTR(numtodsinterval(2.75, 'HOUR'), 15,2) || 'mins:' ||
   SUBSTR(numtodsinterval(2.75, 'HOUR'), 18,2) || 'secs' hoursvalue FROM dual
```

That would return as follows:

**hoursvalue
  2hrs:45mins:00secs**

You can also use query as below which would also return same result:

```
SELECT TRUNC(2.75) || 'hrs:' ||
   extract (minute from numtodsinterval(2.75, 'HOUR' )) || 'mins:' ||
   extract (second from numtodsinterval(2.75, 'HOUR')) || 'secs'  hoursval
FROM dual
```

Comment: I don't think `SUBSTR()` is a smart choice, because the number of digits for "day" can vary. `EXTRACT` is certainly the better solution.